# How can I make a clone draggable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a simple site for school that would allow a user to drag different colored squares into a large div to create an image similar to r/place on reddit. However I can't make the clone draggable.

jQuery:

```
 $(function(){
    $('.ui-widget-content').draggable({
      helper:'clone',
      revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $('#canvas').droppable({
      accept: '.ui-widget-content',
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
      }
    });
});
<div id="canvas">


<div id="color-container">
  <div id = "red" class = "ui-widget-content"> </div>
  <div id = "blue" class = "ui-widget-content"> </div>
  <div id = "green" class = "ui-widget-content"> </div>
  <div id = "yellow" class = "ui-widget-content"> </div>
  <div id = "orange" class = "ui-widget-content"> </div>
</div>

</div> <!-- closes the "canvas" -->
```